# microsoft reportviewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, reportviewer

anyone has a code sample to connect the Microsoft Report Viewer Control
using Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: Could you add more detail the question is not complete. Are you looking for a SP which generates the report?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but there is a lot of good information on this site:

[www.gotreportviewer.com](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/)